# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing the getter on an object created by Spring's class converter

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, converters

I'm converting one object to another object, but when I try to use the getter on the object that was created, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The data is a simple String in the field and is on a very straight-forward object.

I've gotten this same issue with both Spring Boot 2.1.1 & 2.1.7.

***Note:*** To replicate the issue, I have to run using `mvn test`, `mvn install`, or use Eclipse' code coverage tool. Using Eclipse's Run or Debug utils succeeds without error.

#### Exception:

```
[ERROR] storeWithEncryption(com.forms.service.SpringConversionServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.forms.service.SpringConversionServiceTest$To.<init>(SpringConversionServiceTest.java:45)
        at com.forms.service.SpringConversionServiceTest.storeWithEncryption(SpringConversionServiceTest.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

#### Test Class

```
package com.forms.service;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.forms.Application;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
public class SpringConversionServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Test
    public void storeWithEncryption() throws Exception {
        From from = new From();
        from.bob = "nope";
        from.bob2 = "yep";
        new To(conversionService.convert(from, To.class));
    }

    public static final class From {

        String bob;
        String bob2;
    }

    public static final class To {


        public To() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public To(To convert) {
            this.bob = convert.bob;
            this.bob2 = convert.bob2;
        }

        String bob;
        String bob2;
    }
}
```

#### FromToConverter

```
package com.forms.service;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.forms.service.SpringConversionServiceTest.From;
import com.forms.service.SpringConversionServiceTest.To;
import com.forms.service.converter.AbstractReflectionConverter;

@Component
public class FromToConverter extends AbstractReflectionConverter implements Converter<From, To> {

    public To convert(From from) {
        To to = new To();
        try {
            // 1 to 1 conversions
            conversionByReflection(from, to);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The source external Header cannot be converted into an internal Header", e);
        }
        return to;
    }

}
```

#### Application.java

```
package com.forms;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:spring/camel-context.xml" })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. As in: please add the relevant parts of your stack trace.

Comment: Might want to strip out some packge information, you don't really want everyone to know what organization you work for.

Comment: I stripped that down. That is the minimal example.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Fixed. (Stripped it out in a text editor and forgot to put it back in the browser.)

Comment: GhostCat - As soon as I get the chance, I'll try to reduce it further.

Comment: Included the stack trace.

Comment: Included the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get around this issue, I had to change from using spring's reflective ConversionService methods to just manually plugging in the values in the converter.

I won't be marking this as the solution as it doesn't really fix the issue if you need to use reflection, but I'm putting it here to serve as a work-around.